# Recaptcha is not showing in safari, but its working properly in chrome

Tags: html, safari, recaptcha

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFdoC.jpg)

I have used google captcha it's working properly in google chrome but it's not showing in safari browser, I am unable to understand why it's happening.